# Export .eps file from tikz image in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

How can i export .eps file from tikz in overleaf

Comment: why do you need an .eps file? why not a .pdf?

Comment: You could take the pdf and convert it to eps yourself.

Comment: Be aware that overleaf uses an outdated TeX distribution. That means you get an older pdf version. That could give problems ...

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] @Mensch We’re testing TeX Live 2018 (frozen just before TL2019 update) right now. If you have a project that would benefit from the update, please contact us at support@overleaf.com with the project’s URL and we’ll update it for you as soon as the update is ready.